# i want to implement video chatting and voice calling between two clients

Tags: java, video-streaming, serversocket, client-server

Project Help!!

I've created project on chatting over LAN in java

i want to implement video chatting and voice calling between two clients...
...
please help me that how can i stream the video in Java?

what library's should i use . .

or any site from there i get information

plz.

Comment: Looking for Skype alternatives? =D Yeah, i've done that with Python. *almost* done that with Python, PyGame and something else i can't recall from my mind what...

Comment: You might want to try flex ( or flash) . It is much easier that way.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) provides functionality for networked video chatting.

Comment: ya it will provide bt i don hav code if u hav den send me plz . . @ vinod.gupta29@gmail.com